# Unit of stopwatch.Elapsed property

Tags: c#, stopwatch, elapsedtime

I am extremely confused with this `stopWatch.Elapsed` property. It shows the time value in this format [image]

I want to know what should I add in the end of this output. Is it `ms` (`01:20:17.0550410ms`)  or just `s` (`01:20:17.0550410s`)?
And further more if I want to take only the `ms`portion of this output and do some calculation with it which value should I take, is it `.0550410` or `55.041`? My questions might sound silly but I'm really confused!
please help.

Comment: I suggest that instead of asking a basic question that is well documented ([StopWatch.Elapsed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsed.aspx) is obviously a [TimeSpan Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx)), take a look at the documentation first, and if you have trouble converting it to what you want, then ask that as that question is a much better question.

Comment: no no. you did not understood my question. I know I can use TimeSpan. But its not about using that. Its just something similar to TimeSpan but its not TimeSpan!

Comment: Then you have a severe misunderstanding.  As I linked in my previous comment, the Property `.Elapsed` on a Stopwatch is, without a doubt, a `Timespan` Structure.  Either you are confused, or you aren't using .Net.

Comment: You state, in your original question, `stopWatch.Elapsed`. If stopWatch is an object of type `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`, then what you asked about gives you a `TimeSpan`. Perhaps you should clarify how it is not a `TimeSpan`?

Comment: If I delete this question will it increase my reputation? 5 down votes it really sad.

Comment: [Why is reputation loss reverted after downvoted answer/question is delete](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252147/why-is-reputation-loss-reverted-after-downvoted-answer-question-is-deleted).

Comment: If i understood the question this might help you  stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString("fff"); you need to format the timespan. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The unit shown is "fractional parts of a second", to the 7th decimal place - i.e. to the 10-millionth of a second.

Since a millisecond is 0.001 seconds, your number of milliseconds is 55.041.

Now, as everyone else said, use `stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds` (to get all of the milliseconds) or `stopWatch.Elapsed.Milliseconds` (to get all of the milliseconds less than 1 second).

Comment: I don't want to get all of the millisecond. I just want to take from here--- simple. Just knowledge, no coding needed. And yes I am asking a simple basic question. Sometimes basic knowledge gets messed up!

Answer (score 6):

> I am extremely confused with this stopWatch.Elapsed property. It shows the time value in this format

I'll begin at the beginning, just to make sure everything is understood.

Microsoft .Net framework designers have decided that all variables that store information derive from either a [Class or a Struct(ture)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173109.aspx).  Both of these *base types* have some defaults methods.  One of these Methods for a ValueType (which I'll discuss below) is [.ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wb77sz3h(v=vs.110).aspx). When you call the `ToString()` method on a Windows Runtime structure, it provides the default behavior for value types that don’t override `ToString()`.

I will assuming you are talking about the [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class.  The documentation states:

> A Stopwatch instance can measure elapsed time for one interval, or the total of elapsed time across multiple intervals. In a typical Stopwatch scenario, you call the Start method, then eventually call the Stop method, and then you check elapsed time using the Elapsed property.

Before we begin looking at the Properties of the Stopwatch, we need to understand that in order for the Stopwatch to work, there needs to be a way to store a [*Magnitude of Time*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orders_of_magnitude_(time)) (information).  A *Magnitude of Time* in this case a numerical representation of the difference between two points in time; in this case the when the Stopwatch Starts and when the Stopwatch Ends.  Microsoft .Net has created a structure called [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx) to store this value.

Taking a look at the documentation for the property `Stopwatch.Elapsed` it is of the type `TimeSpan`.

[image]

Since your screenshot appears to be in a console application, I'll assume the code (which should **always be provided** but isn't) is the following:

```
Console.Writeline("Took Time: " + stopWatch.Elapsed.ToString());
```

This code converts the `TimeSpan` into a `string` using the [TimeSpan's .ToString() override](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992632(v=vs.110).aspx):

[image]

So not passing a value to `.ToString()` is a null value which defaults to `("c")` It's in the TimeSpan Format Strings:

[image]

So using your example:

```
01:20:17.0550410s
```

It should be obvious that `01` is hours, `20` is minutes, `17` is seconds and `.0550410` are tenths of seconds (decisecond).  Adding any string values at the end will most likely make no sense because all the numbers are of different time durations. The only way I think it would make sense if you wanted be more specific is to change it to:

```
01h 20m 17.0550410s
```

or

```
01h 20m 17s 055.0410ms
```

Answer (score 1):

Elasped is a TimeSpan, what you're showing is the representation from writing it to the console (Same as calling .ToString() on any non string object), that representation is in hours:minutes:seconds.fraction of second. If you want to show this in a specific amount there are properties for this on the TimeSpan so instead of doing

```
Console.WriteLine(stopWatch.Elapsed);
```

You can do

```
Console.WriteLine(stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
```

A full example to clarify

```
Console.WriteLine(
"The timer ran for " + stopWatch.Elapsed.Hours + " Hours, " 
+ stopWatch.Elapsed.Minutes + " Minutes and " 
+ stopWatch.Elapsed.Seconds + ". this amounts to a total of "
+ stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds + " ms" );
```

Comment: OMG! I didn't ask for code!. I asked a simple question but everyone made it a bit too far. sigh!

Comment: It's common to include example code when explaining, i'm confused, are you complaining that people are answering your question and giving example on top, for free on a service website?

Comment: NO..... Its not a complain at all!!! Actually only two people understood my question (if I'm not wrong).  Most of the people didn't even understood what I asked and you just gave code example. Its good but its not what my question is about. please don't mind.

Comment: @Giliweed If you believe only two people understood your question then perhaps that's an indicator that your question was poorly expressed and thus deserving of any downvotes it received?

Comment: @MattCoubrough, may be your right. Next time I will be more careful of my question pattern so that everyone understands. And by the way, yes its sad that I lost a few reputations ,  but someone did clear all my doubts and confusions. So its not so bad after all. :)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation for TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> A TimeSpan value can be represented as [-]d.hh:mm:ss.ff, where [...] ss is seconds, and ff is fractions of a second

So in your case, it is 17.0550410 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are just using the default `.ToString()` method of the `Stopwatch.Elapsed` property, which actually is a `TimeSpan` object. You can absolutely control the string formatting of this TimeSpan, as well as use numeric components of it for mathematical operations (rounding, adding, etc.). Please read this: [Stopwatch.Elapsed Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsed.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

A quick search of 'c# stopwatch' returns the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) showing that `Stopwatch.Elapsed` is a TimeSpan. Then a search on 'c# TimeSpan' returns the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ecy8h51%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) showing that `TimeSpan.ToString()` returns a string with the following format: `[-][d.]hh:mm:ss[.fffffff]`. And that's just using google. Next time try doing some research before asking your question.

Comment: I did searched in Google but did not found what might be the unit! Everywhere it is hh:mm:ss . But this is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are interested in `StopWatch.Elapsed`, then...

In situations like this I find the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsed.aspx) is often quite helpful.

It states that `StopWatch.Elapsed` returns

> A read-only **TimeSpan** representing the total elapsed time measured by the current instance.

The [documentation for TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) states its many available properties, one of which is *Milliseconds* and another is *TotalMilliseconds*. According to the docs:

> Milliseconds - Gets the milliseconds component of the time interval represented by the current TimeSpan structure.

whereas

> TotalMilliseconds  - Gets the value of the current TimeSpan structure expressed in whole and fractional milliseconds.

Other properties allow you to check Days, Hours, Minutes, Seconds etc. Please use the documentation as it saves everyone a lot of time and effort.

Comment: There's no need to assume, the OP states it right in his question.

Comment: The OP doesn't make it clear - especially considering the comments that follow...  I am wary and therefore am qualifying my answer.